# Using Google Map Data API on the Android platform

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-data-api

I was checking out the Google Maps Data API and I was wondering if I can follow their [Java Development guide](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_java.html) to use it on the Android platform? I want to display routes that I have created on Google Maps on the phone.

Ideally this would be through a MapView but if I need to do it a different way I could.

Thanks,
Rob

EDIT: I feel that my question is probably a little too open ended. I don't completely understand how the Google Data API works with Google Maps. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction but if anyone thinks that this is a bad question let me know so I can delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, several android apps use the Maps Data API (My Tracks, for instance). However, you'll need to parse the KML returned from the maps data and then write code to add it to MapView manually.

Comment: Same answer I came too. Thanks!